# Must I install Ubuntu to use it fully?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

What is the difference between running Ubuntu on a Live USB and on internal hard drive?

Comment: I think that you'll need to be more specific with your question in order to get a useful answer. This site works best with objective questions rather than subjective ones. What do you want to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: @Scot or you tell him what the different is in a answer.... ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use a live USB you can't save your work and programs that you install are lost when you shutdown the pc.

When you install Ubuntu you can do everything normal, and install programs and save your work. :)

Comment: You can save the work to a persistent file on the USB stick. And you can also install programs. It can be created using bootstick creators like UNetBootin.

Comment: the_Seppi is right. The Ubuntu Creator for USB Drives (I forgot it's name) allows to preserve space for created data. So I'm not sure about installing applications, but you can definitely store some files.

Comment: Thanks @the_Seppi for that information, didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, I have found the live USB to be slow / sluggish in performance - also, you will not be able to save any changes made once you shutdown

With an install on your HDD, you get the best experience and able to enjoy to its fullest, ie. install / save changes and improved performance levels

I hope that helps

Comment: oh, I don't personnaly find it slow on liveUSB (unless you have a SSD as hard-drive, which is indeed a big deal).